# I dont understand how to write the display_items fucntion

Tags: python

```
class Item:
    def __init__(self, code, desc, price, quantity):
        self.__code = code             # the item code
        self.__description = desc      # the item description
        self.__price = price           # the item unit price
        self.__quantity = quantity     # the number of item available

    def getCode(self):
        return self.__code

    def setCode(self, code):
        self.__code = code;

    def getDescription(self):
        return self.__description

    def setDescription(self, desc):
        self.__description = desc

    def getPrice(self):
        return self.__price

    def setPrice(self, price):
        self.__price = price

    def getQuantity(self):
        return self.__quantity

    def setQuantity(self, quantity):
        self.__quantity = quantity

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Item({0}, {1}, {2}, {3})'.format(self.__code, self.__description, self.__price, self.__quantity)    

    def __str__(self):
        return '{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}'.format(self.__code, self.__description, str(self.__price), str(self.__quantity))

# This function displays all the items on sale.
    def display_items(self):
        for i in range(len(self.__items)):
            if self.__items[i]
            print(self.__items[i])

BC001, Fresh toast bread white (700g), 3.99, 20 
BC002, Low-fat milk (2 liter), 4.8, 10 
BC003, V-energy drink, 2.75, 10 
BC005, Coca-Cola (300 ml), 2.5, 10 
BC006, Pineapple, 3.6, 6 
BC007, Mango, 1.89, 4 
BC008, Snickers chocolate bar, 1.8, 20 
BC009, Broccoli, 1.47, 11 
BC010, Washed Potato (2.5kg), 2.98, 7 
BC011, Good-morning cereal, 5.6, 10 
BC012, Rose apple (1.5kg bag), 4.98, 5 
BC013, Avocado (4pk), 4.99, 5 
BC014, Bananas (850g bag), 2.96, 4 
BC015, Kiwi fruit green (1kg), 2.45, 10 
BC016, Rock melon, 7.98, 2 
BC017, Lettuce, 2.99, 12 
BC018, Chocolate block (200g), 3.59, 10 
BC020, Parsley curly, 1.99, 6 
BC021, Grapefruit 1kg, 3.99, 7
```

Please note that you should only display the items with a quantity value greater than zero. That is, if an item is out of stock (its quantity value is 0), it should not be listed as available on sale. For example, in the above output, item ‘BC004,Fresh garlic (450g)’ was not shown.

Comment: Please post the specific problem you are having. You should try it yourself first.

Comment: But it's already written...

Comment: That last paragraph reads like part of a homework assignment, not a description of the problem you're having.

Answer (score 1):

You want to create a class variable and a class method:

```
class Item:

    instances = []

    @classmethod
    def display_all(cls):
        for item in cls.instances:
            if item.getQuantity() > 0:
                print(item)

    def __init__(self, code, desc, price, quantity):
        Item.instances.append(self)
        ...

    ...
```